# Perl not printing file contents

Tags: perl, file

I'm writing a script in Perl that reads from a file and prints the contents.
It's reading the file without errors, but it's not printing the contents.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use autodie;

my $dir = "/home/user/.fluxbox/.notify/notify";

if ( -e "$dir")
{
 open(NOTE, "+>>", $dir) or die( "Error opening file! $!");

 chomp(my @note = <NOTE>);

 print "File Contents:\n";
 print "@note\n";

 close(NOTE) or die "Can't close $dir: $!";
}
```

Output:

```
 Name "main::NOTE" used only once: possible typo at /path/to/script.pl line 13.
 File Contents:
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you opening for appending that leaves the file offset at the end of the file, so reading will get you an immediate eof.  You need to `seek` backwards (probably you want to the beginning of the file) before reading will get you anything.  Since you're not writing at all, you should probably just open the file for reading only (as others have said)

Comment: Inserting `seek(NOTE, 0, 0);` between `open` and `chomp` worked. I'm getting a warning in `chomp(my @note = <NOTE>);` about `NOTE` only being used once.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.perlfect.com/articles/perlfile.shtml

```
mode          operand    create    truncate
read            <       
write           >          ✓         ✓
append          >>         ✓

Each of the above modes can also be prefixed with the + character 
to allow for simultaneous reading and writing.

mode          operand    create    truncate
read/write     +<       
read/write     +>          ✓         ✓
read/append    +>>         ✓
```

You're using read/append, so it'll read to the EOF and start there.  You need to use `<` to start at the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 2):

The file is being truncated because you're opening it for *writing* (and reading), which, as in C (and some other languages?) means that the file is truncated if it already exists.  If you actually want to add text to the file, you want to open it for *appending* (and reading), which in Perl is done with `'+>>'` instead of `'+>'`.  However, your script doesn't write anything to the file, and your description indicates that you only want to read from it, not write to it, so in that case you should just be opening it for reading only with `'<'`.

Also, you should never, ever, ever use the two-argument form of `open`; always use the three-argument form instead (in this case, `open(NOTE, '+>>', $dir)`).

EDIT: I forgot that opening a file for appening sets the file position to the end of the file, and it's from this position that it will start reading.  If you actually want to read from the file while having the option to append to it (and what you've provided gives no motivation for the latter ability so far), after opening the file, you need to use `[seek][1]` to set the position to the beginning of the file, and *then* reading the file will give you its contents.

Comment: Don't say never ever ever like that.  He's not doing anything wrong there.,

Comment: at least, don't say 'never ever' without some explanation as to why.

Answer (score 1):

You have no idea whether it's getting errors, because you never check for them. Add

```
use autodie;
```

or check your return values properly.  The **only way to know whether** a `readline` or a `print` succeeded is to check the `close`.

```
close(NOTE) || die "can't close $dir: $!";
```

You cannot test the value of `print` or `readline`.  You must check the `close.

There are other issues, but that’s a good start.

Now verify that the file actually has anything in it to read.  Stat it and make sure you read that many bytes. How do you know there is anything there to read?  Your stat is only testing for existence. It doesn't test size, perms, or even file type.

Answer (score 0):

```
open(NOTE, "+>>", $dir) or die( "Error opening file! $!");
```

Your problem is the second argument, '+>>'. When you switch it to `<`, it works. I believe `+>>` means "write+append" whereas `<` means "read."

Answer (score 0):

> I'm writing a script in Perl that reads from a file and prints the
>   contents.

What you need is:

- Get the file name
- Open the filehandle
- Read and print the data

Rather than reading the whole file into memory, it is preferable to use the line-by-line mode of `while`. Using `chomp` will remove the newlines, and garble the output significantly, so don't use that unless you need it.

You don't need to check if the file exists, as `open` and `autodie` will take care of that for you. This script can also be used with a command line argument, e.g. `script.pl filename.txt`. If that is not required, remove `shift ||`.

**Code:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $file = shift || "/home/user/.fluxbox/.notify/notify";

open my $fh, '<', $file;

print "File contents:\n--------------\n";
print while (<$fh>);
```